# Second video card has no output

Tags: xorg, opensuse, nvidia

I am trying to pin down the reason for GPU passthrough not working with my NVidia GTX 750 Ti device. Therefore I am trying to start a second X instance with that video card - the main one is a GTX 1070.

I am connecting them to the same monitor - the 1070 via DisplayPort, the 750Ti via HDMI.

Booting Windows results in both being detected and activated and I get output via both DisplayPort and HDMI.

When booting using Linux the 1070 works without issue. The 750Ti is detected:

```
# nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1070 (UUID: GPU-a66c5cbb-a541-a3d7-845c-f8c0c021ae71)
GPU 1: GeForce GTX 750 Ti (UUID: GPU-db546e26-f6d5-5345-45e4-434e0bfb4f62)
```

and in the nvidia-settings program it is shown as connected to the Monitor.

However, when starting up a second Xorg instance, I get no output on the HDMI port.

The command I use is

```
sudo Xorg :2 vt8 -config xorg-second.conf  -configdir conf.d
```

where conf.d is empty, to make sure no other settings are applied, and [xorg-second.conf](https://pastebin.com/snbGqej0) is pretty much standard except

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

to make sure that the right video card is picked up.

I have tried switching cables, but that did not help.

Why is the second video card not sending output to my monitor and how can I fix it?

---

*Edit*: Here's the output for `xrandr` for both X instances:

```
$ xrandr --display :1
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ xrandr --display :2
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Interesting to note that when I run `xrandr --display :2` the second time, it hangs. The final lines of the `strace` output are

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X2"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X2"}, [124->20]) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="mars", ...}) = 0
access("/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", R_OK) = 0
open("/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=96, ...}) = 0
read(4, "\1\0\0\4mars\0\0\0\22MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1\0\20"..., 4096) = 96
close(4)                                = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX}, [124->2]) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{iov_base="l\0\v\0\0\0\22\0\20\0\0\0", iov_len=12}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1", iov_len=18}, {iov_base="\0\0", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="\36\271\266\234:\323(\237\35y\334(X\37\32\10", iov_len=16}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 6) = 48
recvfrom(3, 0x18dd330, 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1
```

---

*Edit 2*

`$ xset -display :2 q` ( just the part about DPMS )

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Xorg log - https://pastebin.com/fK7g5VSd

Comment: (1) The closed-source `nvidia` driver sometimes does funny things, also try with `nouveau`. (2) What does `xrandr --display :1` say (both for `nvidia` and `nouveau`)? (3) Is this is a laptop? Some laptops have extra hardware to share/switch ports.

Comment: @dirkt - see my update for (2) . For (1) I have no answer since apparently nouveau does not support my 1070 - `X` startup fails with `(EE) Unknown chipset: NV134`. For (3) - not a laptop, using a plain desktop.

Comment: `xrandr` shows the HDMI port properly connected. Do you mean "no output" as in "everything is black"? Have you tried to start applications on the second server? Or a window manager? Another way to test is to use `xsetroot -display :2`, e.g. `xsetroot -display :2 -solid red` or `xsetroot -display :2 -gray`.

Comment: I'm not sure where the hang comes from, it seems to be some kind of problem with the "MIT magic cookie" (used for authorization). What display manager are you using? I know `gdm` hardlinks magic cookies, which is not good. If that is the problem, use the `-auth` option when you start the server to make sure the cookies don't get mixed up.

Comment: 1) no output → black screen, monitor enters power saving mode
2) `DISPLAY=:2 xterm` does nothing
3) `xsetroot -display :2 -solid red` does nothing
4) I tried starting Xorg with `-auth /tmp/bla_auth` but the file does not seem to be created, and a second `xrandr -q` fails in the same way.

Do I need to attach a separate keyboard? It's worth nothing that when starting Xorg the vt switches temporarily ( I guess to vt8 ) but that's a blank screen on the DP output ( blinking cursor )

Comment: I'm still confused why you can't see anything when `xrandr` shows the output as active. Things to try: (1) Switch to vt8 with Ctrl-Alt-F8 etc. after the `xsetroot`, if the non-active vt is blocking the server for some reason (2) `xset -display :2 q` to see if DPMS is enabled. (3) put up `/var/log/Xorg.2.log` to a pastebin, edit question with link. Maybe it contains something that gives a hint.

Comment: Will do once I get to that computer. A quick question - could UEFI play a part? I use a `linuxuefi` boot line and previously the 750Ti was used this way.

Comment: Since the X server comes up, and xrandr is working, I don't see how UEFI could block something. The HDMI port is directly on the card, right?

Comment: @dirkt - see some updates in the question. Also, 1) after running xset -display :2 q and the xsetroot ... call hangs 2) HDMI port is directly on the card, yes

Comment: Your xorg.conf calls for "Monitor0" in the screen section, but I see no definition of "Monitor0" anywhere. You might need to specify that, as well.

Comment: @Mioriin - thanks for the comment. I've linked to the full xorg.conf - https://pastebin.com/snbGqej0 . Monitor0 is defined there.

Answer (score 1):

In the log, you can see that the server at `:2` also detects the main graphics card `GTX 1070 (GP104-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-1)`. This is something that doesn't happen in regular X drivers - if you tell the driver in an `xorg.conf` to only use `PCI:3:0:0`, then it will only use this card, and never see any other card.

So the only explanation I have is that because the closed-source `Nvidia` drivers use a different infrastructure (a unified kernel driver very similar for Windows and Linux), the `Nvidia` drivers are just not made to handle this kind of situation, or they handle it differently. As long as you use the closed-source drivers, it could very well be that a single instance of the kernel-driver is supposed to drive all available cards, and that's it. And nobody really tested using several X servers to connect to that single instance (after all, Nvidia even only provides the nvidia-specific "TwinView" for multiple screens). Not to speak of using one kernel-driver for one card in an VM, and another kernel-driver outside the VM.

And if you can't use the `nouveau` drivers, there's really no way around it.

You can try to use the Nvidia-specific [options for 375.39](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.39/README/xconfigoptions.html), for example set `ProbeAllGpus` to `FALSE` for both servers. Maybe that helps, maybe it doesn't. Possibly `MultiGPU` helps, though I think this is meant for a different situation.

You can also try `ConnectedMonitor` or `UseDisplayDevice` to restrict the display somehow.

The way to test this theory would be to use two Nvidia cards that are also supported by Nouveau, and then see if one can make the Nouveau driver work in this way. Unfortunately, I don't have the hardware to do that.

Comment: Not a definite answer for me, but it is useful so I'd rather not have the bounty go to waste :-)